# Update params or redirect to correct URL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Relatively new to rails, so having trouble coming to a solution for this issue.

Currently have a route: `/test/testing/:id`
Where once a user hits the route, it will find an item in the database with that specific id and set the URL to `localhost:3000/test/testing/1-name-of-this-item`

However, if you just manually type in that URL eg: `localhost:3000/test/testing/1`, I would like it to either redirect to `/test/testing/1-name-of-this-item` OR if there is some way to change the params before the page load. But not entirely sure on how to do this.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How do you set the URL to `/test/testing/1-name-of-this-item` currently in your code? Can you elaborate on why setting that new URL works the use-case of your second paragraph but not in the use-case of the third, what is the difference between both GET requests?

Comment: @spickermann There is currently a table with all of the items in it, there is a link_to on the title of the item, which on click will set the URL, it is then sent to my show action, which queries for the item. If the user somehow entered in the URL with just the id (/test/testing/1) for example, it would still load the page which the functionality I would want is if the id(integer) is just passed in, the page will redirect to the integer and name of the item (test/testing/1-name-of-this-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; there is a gem called refraction that is a middleware that allows you to alter the URL before it is processed by the app, which works well.

https://github.com/joshsusser/refraction

Answer (score 1):

You can try two ways to handle this

1: use the following Gem which will construct URL's based on the attribute you want
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

2: override to_param method in your model and pass the attribute you would like to display in URL path

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above I suppose that you have a `Testing` model that has at least a column named `id` and a column `path`. Because you didn't mention how the path is generated I will just assume that the column is prepopulated and returns slugs like `1-name-of-this-item` and that the number prefixing the path is always in sync with the record's id.

Further, I guess that you have your routes properly set up and that `/test` is a namespace and `/testing` is defined as an ordinary `resources :testing`. That makes me assume that a path_helper like `test_testing_path` was generated by Rails.

If that is the case then it might be enough to just change your `show` controller method to this:

```
def show
  @testing = Testing.find(params[:id])
  
  if @testing.path != params[:id]
    redirect_to test_testing_path(@testing.path)
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @testing }
    end
  end
end
```